# Concatenate Matrix PYTHON (No numpy)

Tags: python, file, matrix

I am to manually merge two given matrices contained in a text file without importing any kind of module. It looks like:

```
[[1,2][3,4]],[[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
```

I have this code:

```
def combine(filename): 
    with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read().split()
        a=data[0].split()
        b=data[1].split()
    a=eval(a[0])
    b=eval(b[0])
    row_a=len(a)
    row_b=len(b)
    col_a=len(a[0])
    col_b=len(b[0])
    concatenated=[]
    if row_a==row_b: #build horizontally 
        for i in range (row_a):
            concatenated.append(a[i])
            for i in range (row_b):
                concatenated.append(b[i])
        return concatenated
    if col_a==col_b: #build vertically
        for i in range (col_a):
            concatenated.append(a[i])
            for i in range (col_b):
                concatenated.append(b[i])
        return concatenated
    else:
        print ("Error")
```

But it returns:

```
[[1, 2], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Instead of:

```
[[1,2,5,6,7],[3,4,8,9,10]]
```

Any ideas on how I can make this work? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
final_results = [a+b for a, b in zip(*ast.literal_eval(open('filename.txt')))]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Edit: without any imports, you can use `eval`. Note however that `eval` is quite insecure and thus must only run on strings from a trusted source:

```
final_results = [a+b for a, b in zip(*eval(open('filename.txt').read()))]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using import? :) Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, if I were to just edit my existing code, is it not possible to just put concatenated=[a+b] under the if statements?

Comment: @FatCat please post the contents of `concatenated` just under the `if` statements.

Comment: Would you know why I get a TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object when I try doing this?

Comment: @FatCat please see my recent edit. It should work now.